# Software to Plot 3D Vector Fields

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I don't have programs like MAthematica or Maple that plot vector fields out of the box, the ones I use are Maxima and Scilab for simbolic/numeric, and none of them can easly plot 3d vector fields, so if someone can plot this one for me, I will appreciate it:
$$ \left( \frac{\cot (\theta)}{r^3},\frac{1}{r^3},0 \right)$$

It's in spherical coordinates

Thanks in advance.
PS: I tried with wolfram alpha but it didn't recognise it. and btw, if someone knows a good free program to do this stuff, please let me know (I used to have a license for Maple from college but I don't have it anymore)

EDIT: The spherical coordinates are in this case: $(r,\theta,\phi)$, where $\theta$ is the angle with ther vertical from 0 when it's vertical, in the direction of z axis, and $\pi$ when it's in the direction of -z axis. $\phi\in (0,2\pi)$

Comment: how about gnuplot? http://www.gnuplot.info/

Comment: [Conventions for spherical coordinates vary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Conventions) You should specify which one you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this online MMA Web Based tool to do a [**3D Plot of Vector Fields**](http://cose.math.bas.bg/webMathematica/MSP/Sci_Visualization/3DVectorField.msp)?

You might also try have a look [*here*](http://softwaretopic.informer.com/3d-vector-field-graphing-software/) and see if any of the free SW listed works for you (GNU Plot, JavaView, Visual Data...).

Have fun!

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the tools, I never liked gnu plot, but looks like I will have to learn it.

Comment: @Ferfer93: Does the MMA not work for you?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, give me a secon, I just saw your answer

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I can't use it, don't know how...

Comment: Nice suggestion! I didn't know that! +1

Comment: Its gone! where did it go? I really want to see this!