# Softwares for animating moving 3-d vector fields?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, math-software, online-resources

I am making a youtube channel where I explain the flow of vector fields and the vector calculus that describes it. The divergence and curl of rivers, the nature of electromagnetism, line integrals through vector fields, etc. I was going to use [manim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENMyFGmq5OA&list=PL2B6OzTsMUrwo4hA3BBfS7ZR34K361Z8F&index=1), but I am making HEAVY use of 3-d vector fields and I am not sure if manim is super good in that regard. Or am I wrong and there are examples of manim usage in this regard that persuade me otherwise?

Matlab? Any online tools you suggest? This is not a duplicate of this question: [Software to Plot 3D Vector Fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277126/software-to-plot-3d-vector-fields) I need there to be motion not just static imagery. If this is not the stack exchange for this tell me where I am supposed to go.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Something like https://anvaka.github.io/fieldplay/ ?

Comment: I have actually seen this, but thank you for sure.

Comment: You think I might go to stack overflow instead?